# Please reopen "How are multicast addresses typically managed?"

Tags: support, reopen-request

[How are multicast group addresses typically managed?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80129/how-are-multicast-addresses-typically-managed)

I've tried to make this question as clear as possible. And I don't believe it is off topic.

It is asking how multicast group addresses are assigned to groups in a typical environment.

I would have thought that multicast and multicast group addresses are quite fundamental to network engineering.

I'm not after software or hardware recommendations to manage addresses.

I'm really trying to inquire if there are standard protocols that assist in management.

MADCAP (RFC 2730) and ZMAAP (IETF draft) are both mentioned in the question as standard protocols that attempt to do that, though it is unclear to me how widespread their use is.

For context, MADCAP is basically DHCP for multicast addresses, and ZMAAP is Zeroconf.

It's possible that there are no standard protocols that are used, but I think that would made a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

> It is asking how multicast group addresses are assigned to groups in a
> typical environment.

That is something handled by application developers, not network engineers. That is off-topic.

> I'm really trying to inquire if there are standard protocols that
> assist in management.

That is a resource recommendation, and that is explicitly off-topic.

> For context, MADCAP is basically DHCP for multicast addresses, and
> ZMAAP is Zeroconf.

DHCP is an application-layer protocol that is off-topic.

> It's possible that there are no standard protocols that are used, but
> I think that would made a good answer.

Protocol theory questions for protocols at or below OSI layer-4 are on topic, but there is nothing in there to manage anything like that. You are asking about off-topic protocols, seeking an off-topic recommendation, not even asking about protocol theory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139651/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-maupin-please-reopen-how-are-multicast-addresses-ty).

Answer (score 1):

The question is ultimately soliciting opinions -- how do *you* manage site/org local multicast groups? There are many corners to this cube...

- The app developer who needs a number to put in the code, or default configuration. In this case, the developer is unlikely to have an admin or engineer who can give them any type of intelligent answer. They aren't likely to even know there's an IANA process to request their very own "well known" registered address, so anything they pick could overlap with anyone else's "random" selection.
- The person tasked with installing the software. They, too, may not have a well of knowledge from which to dip.

Now let's say you do have a Networking IT group to ask. You might *assume* they keep track of multicast address space just like they do unicast. Unless the enterprise extensively uses multicast, it's highly unlikely anyone is maintaining a list of multicast addresses and/or users. (I've worked for / with many very large enterprises, none have ever kept a list of multicast groups. I did briefly while testing VXLAN tech.)

As a network engineer, I would be very happy for any coworker to ask me for a multicast address... rather than them trying to figure it out themselves and blindly using 224.0.0.1. (those people get their ports disabled, and a long talking to when they come to have them re-enabled.) The internet is full of fools who have done that, and the fools who read their blog posts and copy it.

--

If you know of two protocols of interest, then search for projects that implement them, and dig around for how many are using those projects. In this case, both are very small numbers.